# last part of resource ID into var

Tags: javascript, html

For the last couple of days I've been working on this website: [bubbles](http://van-der-noord.nl/bubbles)
When you enter the site, a popup is shown and you are asked to enter a word. When you enter a word, the word will be displayed on the website, in a bubbly font.
There also are a few 'easter eggs', e.g. when you type in 'orca'.

Now my question is, how could I make it so that the last part of the link, is automatically the myName var? (I don't know how to explain it really...)

So when you go to http://van-der-noord.nl/bubbles/here, it should display [image: One]

And when you go to http://van-der-noord.nl/bubbles/penguin it should display

[image: penguins]

Comment: You need server-side support for a link structure like that. If you're ok with `http://example.com/bubbles/#penguin` (or `?penguin`) then that's doable in plain JavaScript.

Comment: Okay tnx! And how do I make my js notice that the user is on #penguin? (I'd prefer # over ?)

Comment: `window.location.hash`

Comment: And if I wanted to do it server-side, could I use PHP?

Comment: And how do I do that in php?

Comment: PHP is too hard.. I'll stick with javascript...

Comment: @Juhana do you know how to automatically redirect example.com/bubbles/something to example.com/bubbles/#something ?
So that people can type it in easily..

Comment: Okay I kinda cheated... But I used this:
    `var url = window.location.pathname;
    var myName = url.split("/").slice(-1)[0];`
And a .htaccess file
I don't really know how it works, but it works, so I'm happy :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Juhana said, the easiest way is with a URL like this:

```
http://example.com/bubbles/#penguin
```

The part starting with `#` is called the "hash," and you can access it with:

```js
window.location.hash // => "#penguin"
```

You can get everything after the `#` with `slice`:

```js
window.location.hash.slice(1) // => "penguin"
```

Comment: It worked thank you! Now I can continue my journey ;)